# How to create Dropdown in Rich Text Editor (wysiwyg) in Sitecore 9.0.2

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor, richtext-editor

I am trying to create a `Dropdown in WYSIWYG`. I have added the Item using the `Html Editor Drop Down Button` template and Dropdown values using the `Html Editor List Item` in the core database. However, it's not showing the values when I open the RTE. Is there any configuration file that I need to edit as well?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide screenshots to what you have set up so far?

Comment: @Asad: This blog post describes the detailed steps to configure a custom dropdown list button in the Rich Text Editor in Sitecore 9: https://sitecorerunner.com/2018/08/21/adding-rte-richtext-custom-dropdown-list-in-sitecore-9/

Comment: @AlessandroFaniuolo Thank you for sharing the link. Do we have to override the EditorConfiguration.cs even if we are using the Sitecore HTML Editor Profiles template to create Sitecore items? So my understanding was that it should work once you add the items as the child list items under the dropdown button.

Comment: @MichaelWest , Please see the screenshots of the items that I added for the Dropdown.

Comment: @Asad You don't need to override it, unless you want to organize the items to list in the dropdown field under a separate folder, instead of creating them as child items of your "Html Editor Drop Down Button" custom item.

Comment: @AlessandroFaniuolo Thank you for your quick reply. So it's not showing the child items even I have added the child items under the Dropdown button. When I changed the Edit Dropdown button Click field to "Zoom" then it shows all the Zoom items. It seems like the value in the Click field has a reference somewhere where it's pulling all the items and that I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: @Asad I looked at the `EditorConfiguration` class code and it looks you need to use the `Html Editor Custom Drop Down Button` template. I think this is worth to call out in an answer, so I created one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blog post describes the detailed steps to configure a custom dropdown list button in the Rich Text Editor in Sitecore 9: https://sitecorerunner.com/2018/08/21/adding-rte-richtext-custom-dropdown-list-in-sitecore-9/

One thing that is not explicitly called out in the article is that you need to use the `Html Editor Custom Drop Down Button` template when creating a custom dropdown button item, instead of the `Html Editor Drop Down Button` template, if you want that the dropdown button lists the child items defined using `Html Editor List Item` template.

Indeed in the `Sitecore.Shell.Controls.RichTextEditor.EditorConfiguration` class, the `SetupToolbar` method invoked to configure each button has a conditional logic based on the template of the button items to initialize buttons in different ways. In particular, when the template name of the button item is `Html Editor Custom Drop Down Button`, the internal `SetChildren` method is called to initialize the list of items to populate the drowdown:

```
private static void SetChildren(EditorDropDownItemCollection items, Item parent)
{
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) items, nameof (items));
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) parent, nameof (parent));
      foreach (Item child in parent.Children)
      {
        if (child.TemplateName == "Html Editor List Item")
          ((EditorNameValueItemCollection<EditorDropDownItem>) items).Add(child["Header"], child["Value"]);
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. This makes sense and it worked perfectly.